# Compare the data in an image and a file

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I have an image file with a graph in it. For instance:
[image: USA map]

1. How can I efficiently extract this graph? Could you point me some examples/concepts?
2. I have a data file containing the edge details and I could plot them on a map to create an image (like the one shown in the link) but with a different background. How can I compare the two and say that there is a match/mismatch?

Any help/comments/thought is much appreciated.

Comment: Be more specific please. What do you mean by extracting this graph ? Do you mean you want to effectively find the names of the cities, and to whom they are connected to ? And you want to do that by processing that single image ? Do you want to do this only for that image or do you have other kinds of images ? If you do this, then the second question becomes trivial.

Comment: Hi mmgp, thanks for your reply! I exactly wanna do that. Find the names of the cities and to whom they are connected to. And by other kinds do you mean different formats or different backgrounds?

Comment: I meant whether you wanna do this only for this image or if you wanna do this for a collection of different images.

Comment: A collection of images would be useful, thanks!

Comment: Can't be done then, I have no idea how this collection of images is.

Comment: If it is a single image?

Comment: It is possible to make it work for this single image, but it will hardly be useful.

Comment: I have a many other single images that has such graphs. Could you point me to some solution? And by collection I meant different images with different graphs!

Comment: That's a whole image processing/recognition thing.  If it was always the same map of the US and you only needed to recognize the cities and the routes, it would probably be moderately simple.  But generalizing it would be difficult at best, and would require some actual work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this can be hardly replicated for different images, this is only a overview of something that works for this specific image.

First convert your image to CMYK and consider the third channel ('Y') to binarize (80% of max, your vertices are relative yellow) to find the vertices:

[image]

Now consider the second channel ('M') to binarize (80% of max again) to find the edges:

[image]

Now if you consider each vertex as a connected component and each edge as connected components too, then you can construct a graph simply by considering the both images at the same time and taking into consideration which edges a given vertex touches.

You can now convert your input image to grayscale in order to find the text. In this simple image, some ad-hoc connected component analysis and simple threshold will give all the text:

[image]

If I run some pretty basic text recognition on this last image, I get:

```
Seattle
Chicago
Bay Area DC Metro NYC
Denver
Los
Angeles
Phoenix
```

Which is pretty nice since it found all the text. All that is left is giving names to your vertices in the already built graph. To do that, consider where a block of text appears and proceed to find the closest edge (first image, just a euclidean distance to the centroids).

If it matters, here is the code to obtain these results:

```
f = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP3la.png"]
cmyk = ColorSeparate[f, "CMYK"]
vertex = Binarize[cmyk[[3]], 0.8]   (* The first image *)
edge = Binarize[cmyk[[2]], 0.8]     (* The second image *)
nyctext = SelectComponents[
  DeleteSmallComponents[
   SelectComponents[Binarize[ColorConvert[f, "Grayscale"], 0.01], 
    Small]], "Length", #1 < 25 &]
alltext = ImageAdd[
  SelectComponents[
   ColorNegate[Binarize[ColorConvert[f, "Grayscale"], 0.5]], Small], 
    nyc_text]                       (* The last image *)
TextRecognize[alltext]              (* The text recognized *)
```